# How to find a title change in a year

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find the number of employees which have a title change in the following table.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/sakila-structure.html

```
titles
    emp_no int
    title varchar
    from_date date
    to_date date
```

The employees which are currently active have a date of 9999-01-01 in their to_date column.  I want to find the number of employees which have a title change in the year 2016.

Comment: The path to happiness starts with a `self join`.

Comment: What have you tried? Self join, Not exists, not in... having.... lots of options here...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the actual schema you provided in the comments to Darshan's answer, you don't need a self join.

```
SELECT count(*) as EmployeeCount
    FROM employees e 
    JOIN titles t ON e.emp_no = t.emp_no
WHERE t.from_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```